# Will setState complete before other events are handled?

Tags: reactjs

When `setState()` is asynchronous, can we be sure, that `this.state` is up to date in events that were fired afterwards? Simple example: a counter with two buttons. One button increments the counter, another button prints `this.state` to the console. If we click "increase" and then "print" immediately, is it 100% guaranteed, that we will see the updated value or might it happen that the second event runs before `setState` completes?

```
class Counter extends Component {
    state = {counter: 0};

    incCounter = () => this.setState(prevState => ({
        counter: prevState.counter + 1
    }));

    logCounter = () => console.log(this.state.counter);

    render = () => (
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.logCounter}>Log</button>
            <button onClick={this.incCounter}>Inc</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*Technically*, yes.  `setState` is asynchronous, and there's no guarantee that the state will have updated before the button is clicked.

... but in practice, we're talking about an window of about 2-4 milliseconds before the state is applied: that's not going to be a big enough window for a user interaction, like clicking a different button.

You can measure the size of this window yourself, using the second argument to setState, which executes when the state has been updated:

```
const start = Date.now();
this.setState(newState, () => {
    const end = Date.now();
    console.log(`Took ${end - start} ms to apply state`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

React prioritizes `setState()`, but sometimes the new state will not be set when you expect it to.

If you want to be sure you are using the new state, right after using `setState()`, you can use the callback function.

```
this.setState({
    someState: true,
},() => {
    console.log(this.state.someState); // Will be new state every time
});
```

Comment: Right, thank you. But this doesn't help me, when we're talking about different methods, right? I've added some code above. The question is, if it is technically possible that the user clicks the two buttons so fast that the printed output might be wrong.

Comment: @K.D. Yeah, there is a possibility that that will happen, but you will never be able to replicate it with mouse clicks, maybe a script. Since the time it takes for setState() to run is way too short.

Answer (score -1):

yes the second event **can** run and complete before `setState` completes for first event. This is a possible situation and can happen if the window of firing events is in between`2-4 ms` . If you want to get updated state always then you have to bind the function as a callback of `setState`

Comment: What do you mean? The render method binds "increase" and "print" methods on the two buttons. If I use `setState` with a callback, how does this affect the print method?

Comment: as '`setstate' is asynchronous , so there can be a situation where you might not get the updated state value in your print method.